# Search string in text file : name not defined error python3

Tags: python

Hi I want to search a string in a text file using python. I am using python3.

Here is my code :-

```
def check():
        datafile = open('testfile.txt')
        found = False
        for line in datafile:
            if good in line:
                found = True
                break

        return found

found = check()
if found:
    print ("String found")
else:
    print ("not found")
```

Here testfile.txt is a text file which contains the string "good". So, expected output should be "String found". But, it is showing error "NameError: name 'good' is not defined'.

Comment: `good` is not a string; `'good'` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to put quotes around what you want to be a string.
Changing `good` to either `'good'` or `"good"` will fix your problem.

There are some other problems with this code though, you are forgetting to close the file for one.
Your code should look more like:

```
def check():
    with open('testfile.txt') as datafile:
        found = False
        for line in datafile:
            if 'good' in line:
                found = True
                break
    return found
```

If you edit python in an IDE ( such as `IDLE` ) you will notice mistakes like these easier because syntax highlighting will usually highlight the string, but not highlight variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for the string 'good', you need to surround it with quotes. Right now the program thinks you are trying to find something stored in the variable named good, and that variable does not exist.

```
if 'good' in line:
```

That should fix your problem.

Edit in response to comment:
You can return the line where the string was found and add it to your print statement.

```
def check():
        datafile = open('testfile.txt')
        found = False
        for line in datafile:
            if 'good' in line:
                found = True
                break
        return found, line

found, line = check()
if found:
    print ("String found: " + line)
else:
    print ("not found")
```

Comment: yes, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, need one more help. If I want to print that line which contain that word then what should I do?

Comment: did it. Thanks. Approving your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the approval!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x.find('my string')` object it checks a string and returns how many times the substring you are looking for is mentioned. if it doesnt exist it should return a 0. maybe this is a more pythonian way of doing this?? hope this helps =)